# How to know priority I18n rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not know `config.i18n.load_path` and `I18n.load_path` difference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880561/config-i18n-load-path-and-i18n-load-path-difference

## devise-i18n-views

I use https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views.

## Directory

[image]

## My project have three I18n for user attributes.

```
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
```

in `config/locales/models/*.yml`, `config/locales/devise*.yml`, `gems/devise-i18n-views-0.3.5/locales/*.yml`.

## Run

I think the priority.

1. config/locales/models/*.yml
2. config/locales/devise*.yml
3. gems/devise-i18n-views-0.3.5/locales/*.yml

## How to know the priority

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html not say about priority for I18n.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that knowing the priority would help you.

The thing is, when you change some of your locale files in development mode, while your server still running, the changed file will be reloaded, and will override the existing `activerecord.attributes.user` scope.

So i think the most reliable way would be to extract `activerecord` scope to a `activerecord.yml` file.